# Появляется пустая область в шаблоне

Tags: css

Появляется пустая область в шаблоне при достижении 347 в ширину
не могу убрать никак[image: Изображение]

[Ссылка на сайт](http://biz-trans.in.ua/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас `head` и `footer` имеет фиксированную ширину:

```
.head {
    width: 330px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.head a {
    width: 300px;
}

.footer {
    width: 980px;
}
```

Comment: оо а яего не могу найти, а в каком он файле?

Comment: wp-content/themes/wshop/style.css

Comment: Получилось))))Спасибо большое

Comment: @kursof, если вам дали правильный ответ - поставьте галку напротив ответа, чтобы его зафиксировать.